# How to implement the smash effect in uibutton

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am using uibutton to smack that to interact it like fruit ninja ,i don't want to cut it , just interact the uibutton to smack it,how to implement that help me how to do that.

Comment: You don't use buttons for this, you should use gestures.

Comment: You need to implement a swipegesture

Comment: @Rob but without buttons how can i will implement that,image view or any other send me reference link to study,i am new for dis.

Comment: @Balaji Can you explain what `xcode` has to do with this question?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `UIButton` use a `UIImageView` and set it's `userInteractionEnable` property to true.
Add a swipe gesture to that `imageView`, It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The control used is swipe gesture on the view ,Not the uibutton with button click event.
[A nice tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more)

Comment: i saw that link its moving the image ,i want to smack it,i am using uibutton touch inside method to interact,now i would like to smack it like fruit ninja to interact uibutton.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`UISwipeGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *mSwipeUpRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething)];

[mSwipeUpRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];

[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:mSwipeUpRecognizer];

[mSwipeUpRecognizer release];
```

And in your `.h` file, add the delegate:

```
<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```